# How to make native mongoDB query in Morphia?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I want to make native MongoDB query in Morphia. Is it possible or Morfia doesn't define this feature?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your query string using `com.mongodb.BasicDBObject#parse(java.lang.String)` to get your query in to a `DBObject`.  Then you can create your query using `AdvancedDatastore#createQuery(Class<T>, com.mongodb.DBObject)` at which point you'll have a "normal" `Query` which you can execute like any other `Query`.  The `Datastore` reference you have lying around is-a `AdvancedDatastore` so you need only cast that reference to have access to that method.

It's on my roadmap to expose this much more cleanly in 2.0 but I'm furiously wrapping up 1.5 development so I can focus on 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer in the right direction - I made this work:
`
BasicDBObject parse = BasicDBObject.parse("{location:{$near:{$geometry:{type: 'Point', coordinates: ["+ location[0]+","+location[1]+"]}, $maxDistance: "+ maxDistance+"}}}");
        Query<LabDataDTO> query = ((AdvancedDatastore) MorphiaHandler.getStore()).createQuery(LabDataDTO.class, new Document(parse));
`
How do you do that neatly in 2.0? Cant find it in the documentation...